# How to obtain the discounted price for Listing?

Tags: json, etsy

I'm trying to obtain the Listing price via the Etsy API. But I stuck in a problem with discounted prices.

There is a listing that I'm trying to obtain: https://www.etsy.com/listing/679432133/turkish-kilim-geometric-kilim-handmade. It's original price is $590 and discounted price is $236.

The problem is that I get only the original price via open API: https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings/679432133/?api_key=MY_KEY&fields=price, but I need to obtain the discounted one.

I'm reading the documentation already for the past three years but it looks like it's impossible via API.

Any help?

Comment: The new api (authenticated request => `https://api.etsy.com/v3/application/shops/<shop_id>/transactions/<transaction_id>`) DOES provide this detail, it seems. I'm able to see `{..."buyer_coupon":1.23, "shop_coupon":1.23}` in addition to the original price. (I came across here trying to google what the difference is between the two coupons, as their values are identical for at least the ones I looked up.)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, getting the discounted price is not available when getting listings via the API.  Mainly because the discounted price is not an attribute of the Listing itself.  Rather, the discounted price is usually derived from applying any number of coupons/sales/promotions from within your shop.

For example, if you have listing A at $100.  Then run a 50% off sale for any quantity purchased... then the discount price is $50.  Then if you edit the sale to require a purchase quantity of 2 or more... then the price is back to $100.  And if you offer a coupon for a specific item for 10% off, now the price is $90.

All of this is just to illustrate how the discounted price for a listing is not really a direct attribute of the listing alone... but rather is a "derived" price.

If you want to know the discounted price, then the closest thing that I can think of is that you would have to use the API to add the listing to a cart.  That will return the contents of the Cart that does have a field named "discount_amount" that will let you detect any line item discounts applied to the cart.  From there you could subtract the "discount_amount" from the "total" to try and calculate the discount price.

At best, however, this would be an approximation of the discount price you are looking for.